Could not give the Result part of the RotateAbsolute action for the turtlesim package of the humble distro
The interface of the RotateAbsolute action is defined as follows:
# The desired heading in radians
float32 theta
---
# The angular displacement in radians to the starting position
float32 delta
---
# The remaining rotation in radians
float32 remaining

I wrote the following code that correctly involved both the desired heading and the remaining rotation, but I could not print the angular displacement as the turtle rotated.
import rclpy
from rclpy.action import ActionClient
from rclpy.node import Node
from turtlesim.action import RotateAbsolute

class RotateAbsoluteClient(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('rotate_absolute_client')
        self.action_client = ActionClient(self, RotateAbsolute, '/turtle1/rotate_absolute')

    def send_goal(self):

        goal_msg = RotateAbsolute.Goal()
        goal_msg.theta = 1.0  # Set the desired heading in radians

        self.get_logger().info(f'Sending RotateAbsolute action goal with theta: {goal_msg.theta} radians...')
        future = self.action_client.send_goal_async(goal_msg, feedback_callback=self.feedback_callback)

        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)  # Wait for the future to complete
        self.process_result(future.result())  # Define a function to handle the result

    def feedback_callback(self, feedback_msg):
        self.get_logger().info(f'Remaining rotation: {feedback_msg.feedback.remaining} radians')

    def process_result(self, result):
        
        self.get_logger().info(f'Goal result: {result}')

def main():
    rclpy.init()
    rotate_client = RotateAbsoluteClient()
    rotate_client.send_goal()
    rclpy.spin(rotate_client)  
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


The implementation of the code is as following:
[INFO] [1714630027.423309476] [rotate_absolute_client]: Sending RotateAbsolute action goal with theta: 1.0 radians...
[INFO] [1714630027.428853147] [rotate_absolute_client]: Goal result: ClientGoalHandle <id=[ 84 240 230 214 157 187  76  51 130 148  75 201   2  58 180 166], accepted=True, status=2>
[INFO] [1714630027.430017681] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 1.0 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.444172395] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.984000027179718 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.459812345] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.9679999947547913 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.475744564] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.9520000219345093 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.491464814] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.9359999895095825 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.507679854] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.9200000166893005 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.523502577] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.9039999842643738 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.540854175] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.8880000114440918 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.557999152] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.871999979019165 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.571389095] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.8560000061988831 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.587309034] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.8400000333786011 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.604233055] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.8240000009536743 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.620439586] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.8079999685287476 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.635939042] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.7919999957084656 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.651976436] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.7760000228881836 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.667989864] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.7599999904632568 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.684427249] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.7439999580383301 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.700433830] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.7279999852180481 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.716718087] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.7120000123977661 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.732193925] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.6959999799728394 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.748211146] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.6800000071525574 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.764543183] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.6640000343322754 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.780232929] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.6480000019073486 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.796248799] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.6319999694824219 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.812113518] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.6159999966621399 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.828044735] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.6000000238418579 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.843781631] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.5839999914169312 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.859660895] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.5679999589920044 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.875864217] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.5519999861717224 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.891757988] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.5360000133514404 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.907834557] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.5199999809265137 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.924192837] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.5040000081062317 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.940002332] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.48799997568130493 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.956013456] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.47200000286102295 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.971947134] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.4559999704360962 radians
[INFO] [1714630027.988118367] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.4399999976158142 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.004019665] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.4240000247955322 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.020439537] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.40799999237060547 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.036870605] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.3920000195503235 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.053539571] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.37599998712539673 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.068357858] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.36000001430511475 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.084531974] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.343999981880188 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.100541659] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.328000009059906 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.116489812] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.31199997663497925 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.131333144] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.29600000381469727 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.148291002] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.2799999713897705 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.164220761] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.2639999985694885 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.180294661] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.24800002574920654 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.196239449] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.23199999332427979 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.212093667] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.2160000205039978 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.227948369] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.19999998807907104 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.244042962] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.18400001525878906 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.260015189] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.1679999828338623 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.276370876] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.15200001001358032 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.292277196] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.13599997758865356 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.308405851] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.12000000476837158 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.324387062] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.10399997234344482 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.340193191] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.08799999952316284 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.357194106] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.07200002670288086 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.378948787] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.0559999942779541 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.387865093] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.04000002145767212 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.403723432] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.02399998903274536 radians
[INFO] [1714630028.419603760] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.008000016212463379 radians


How can I print the Result part of the action, namely  the angular displacement in radians to the starting position, as I did with the remaining rotation in radians

After reading the official tutorial materials, I rewrote the code as follows:
import rclpy
from rclpy.action import ActionClient
from rclpy.node import Node
from turtlesim.action import RotateAbsolute

STATUS_MESSAGES = {
    0: "Pending - The operation represented by the future has not yet completed.",
    1: "Completed - The operation represented by the future has completed successfully.",
    2: "Cancelled - The operation represented by the future was cancelled before completion",
    3: "Finished with an error - The operation represented by the future encountered an error during execution.",
    4: "Unknown - The status of the future is unknown or not applicable."
}

class RotateAbsoluteClient(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('rotate_absolute_client')
        self.action_client = ActionClient(self, RotateAbsolute, '/turtle1/rotate_absolute')

    def send_goal(self):
        goal_msg = RotateAbsolute.Goal()
        goal_msg.theta = 2.0  # Set the desired heading in radians

        self.get_logger().info(f'Sending RotateAbsolute action goal with theta: {goal_msg.theta} radians...')
        self._send_goal_future = self.action_client.send_goal_async(goal_msg, feedback_callback=self.feedback_callback)
        self._send_goal_future.add_done_callback(self.goal_response_callback)

    def goal_response_callback(self, future):
        goal_handle = future.result()
        status = goal_handle.status
        message = STATUS_MESSAGES.get(status)
        if message:
            self.get_logger().info(message)
        else:
            self.get_logger().info(f"Unknown status code: {status}")

        if not goal_handle.accepted:
            self.get_logger().info('Goal rejected :(')
            return

        self.get_logger().info('Goal accepted :)')

        self._get_result_future = goal_handle.get_result_async()
        self._get_result_future.add_done_callback(self.get_result_callback)

    def get_result_callback(self, future):
        status = future.result().status
        message = STATUS_MESSAGES.get(status)
        if message:
            self.get_logger().info(message)
        else:
            self.get_logger().info(f"Unknown status code: {status}")
        result = future.result().result
        self.get_logger().info('Result: {0}'.format(result.delta))
        rclpy.shutdown()

    def feedback_callback(self, feedback_msg):
        self.get_logger().info(f'Remaining rotation: {feedback_msg.feedback.remaining} radians')

    def process_result(self, result):
        # Check for success/failure and handle accordingly
        self.get_logger().info(f'Goal result: {result}')

def main():
    try:
        rclpy.init()
        rotate_client = RotateAbsoluteClient()
        rotate_client.send_goal()
        rclpy.spin(rotate_client)  # Spin the node to wait for callbacks
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    finally:
        if rclpy.ok():
            rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


The outcome from running the code:
[INFO] [1714724281.605038499] [rotate_absolute_client]: Sending RotateAbsolute action goal with theta: 2.1 radians...
[INFO] [1714724281.621636319] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.11599993705749512 radians
[INFO] [1714724281.622596622] [rotate_absolute_client]: Cancelled - The operation represented by the future was cancelled before completion
[INFO] [1714724281.623086762] [rotate_absolute_client]: Goal accepted :)
[INFO] [1714724281.637303715] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.09999990463256836 radians
[INFO] [1714724281.653035164] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.0839998722076416 radians
[INFO] [1714724281.669173255] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.06799983978271484 radians
[INFO] [1714724281.685028698] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.051999807357788086 radians
[INFO] [1714724281.700725862] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.03600001335144043 radians
[INFO] [1714724281.716536476] [rotate_absolute_client]: Remaining rotation: 0.019999980926513672 radians
[INFO] [1714724281.717126483] [rotate_absolute_client]: Unknown - The status of the future is unknown or not applicable.
[INFO] [1714724281.717595742] [rotate_absolute_client]: Result: -0.09600000083446503


All seems good except that the status of the future object is confusing, sometimes it is 4, or 2 at some other times. It will be highly appreciated if someone can explain this to me.
